# AWS SQS Policy not restricting root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, policy

I created some SQS queues as a root user. - Now when I like to restrict access via policies it does not seem to work. - Even with a test policy like this

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "PolicyDenyTest",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyIt",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "sqs:DeleteMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:SendMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxx:TST"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can still send/retrieve/delete messages from the queue from my local machine. - Are policies only valid when  creating queues with an IAM user?

Comment: What user/role is your local machine using?

Comment: I am using access/secret from root acount

Comment: Could you double check the ARN value in the "Resource" key?

Comment: It is correct - I copied it directly from the SQS console - just for stackoverflow in my question I overwrote with 'xxx'

Comment: I just created a new IAM user with full permissions for SQS and used that access key on my local machine - I got properly denied but when switching back to root keys I can process. - My final goal is restricting to internal VPC of my EC2's so no outside access would be possible (even with root keys) but it seems that root keys can bypass policy which seems wrong to me.

Comment: What if you explicitly deny it in principle? `"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:root"`

Comment: Makes no difference - tried before and retested again. - I will move all my apps to use the new IAM user keys and later regenerate the root key.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for testing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The credentials of the account owner allow full access to all resources in the account. You cannot use IAM policies to explicitly deny the root user access to resources. You can only use an AWS Organizations service control policy (SCP) to limit the permissions of the root user. Because of this, we recommend that you create an IAM user with administrator permissions to use for everyday AWS tasks and lock away the access keys for the root user.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html

The root key is all-powerful key that can be used to recover everything even if you mistakenly deny all access to all your resources. This is a well thought-out decision that is explained in the linked doc